# Fazer Troca De Número Na Ordem Decrescente

Tags: javascript

Desejo criar um contador automático, que venha marcando em que número se encontra a cada segundo.

Para isso acontecer, tenho em mente que ele deverá pular de um *elemento* `<a>` para outro a cada segundo.

Estou efetuando testes manualmente, para depois programar a auto-contagem.

A lógica toda é simples, a cada clique uma descida para um número anterior

## Código

```js
el = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

var x = 0, y = 0;

function voltar()
{
if(y == 6 || x == 0) 
alert("Limite!");
else {
el[x].style.color = "red";
el[y].style.color = "black";
}
x--;
}
```

```css
a
{ 
text-decoration: none;

cursor: pointer;

padding: 3px; 

color: black; 
}
```

```html
<a onclick="voltar(x--)" id="menos">Você está no:</a>

<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
<a style="color:red">5</a>
```

**A cada clique** na palavra *Você está no:* então ele deveria descer para o **número menor/antecessor**

> **NOTA -** a cor anterior deve ser restaurada, ficando em cor vermelho só o número em destaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações com seu snippet.
Verifique se é isso que você quer.

```js
el = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

var x = 0;

function voltar(limit)
{
  
  if(x == 0) x = limit;

for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
  el[i].className = "";
}
  el[x].className = "color";
  
  x--;

}
```

```css
a
{ 
text-decoration: none;

cursor: pointer;

padding: 3px; 

color: black; 
}

.color {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<a onclick="voltar(5)" id="menos">Você está no:</a>


<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
<a class="red">5</a>
```

Comment: Não se esqueça de passar como parâmetro na função a quantidade de números que tem nas âncoras. Assim, você tem a flexibilidade de criar quantas âncoras forem preciso, como: `<a>..</a>
<a>10</a>
<a>11</a>
<a>12</a>`
Neste caso, você deve passar 12 como parâmetro inicial.